# How to calculate 1-step ahead volatility for IGAARCh(1,1)

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, garch, volatility

[image]

I need some pointers to solve this question?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you ask your question using mathjax. It is not easy to read the maths expressions.

Comment: @AbdoulHaki I have attached an image unfortunately don't know how Mathjax works?

Comment: You just have to replace $a_{996}$ and $\sigma_{996}$ in the $\sigma_t^2$ equation and get the forecast

Comment: Are u sure?Because I though first we have to convert equation into standard IGARCH format?I am a newbie in Time Series  so confused?

Comment: Even if you transform it, the equation will remain true. So, you can you it directly.